# Why was Michael Jackson so important to Cameron/Sarah Connor?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

> August 29, 1997, came and went. Nothing much happened. **Michael Jackson turned 40**. ([*Terminator 2: Judgement Day* quote](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103064/quotes))

Out of all possible events happening on Judgement Day, choosing a pop singer's birthday seems... kinda dull. I mean, if you have to pick an entertainer, pick someone with importance and gravitas (Sir Attenborough?). Or Stephen Wolfram (who'd also be *way* on topic, what with Wolfram Alpha). Or James Brady - he's just as famous as Jackson and a lot more important in the big scheme of things.

**Is there something special about Michael Jackson that warranted that line? Special in-universe relationship (e.g. Connor being noted as a super-fan) or out-of-universe (script writer or Cameron a fan, or explaining why they put in that line)?**

Comment: Sadly, it was probably because MJ was/is more commonly known. For the people in the theater, hearing about someone they've never heard turning 40 doesn't have as much of an impact.

Comment: I thought "Michael Jackson turned 40" was supposed to mesh with the idea that "nothing much happened": it's supposed to be mundane and irrelevant and boring. If she had picked someone really important it wouldn't have been what she meant. If the movie was made today she could have picked a Kardashian, for example.

Comment: `choosing a pop singer's birthday seems... kinda dull.` - Yeah, I think that was the point.  Not much happened.

Comment: Also, I had to look up James Brady to be sure you weren't referring to [The Brady Bunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brady_Bunch).  He's not nearly as famous as Michael Jackson.  Remember _Brave New World_:  Entertainment trumps all  =P

Comment: You're facing this with a North-American vision. However, Terminator 2 was made for the whole world. For instance, Mr Attenborough, Stephen Wolfram or James Brady are unkwon people in Europe (At best, some people would recognise their faces)

Comment: You don’t think Michael Jackson was an important entertainer? I’m not sure you should be discussing pop culture if that’s true.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - You don't notice me as a high-rep user on pop-music.SE, right? :)

Comment: @ArcDare - Sorry, that's... 100% wrong on many leves. First of all, I wasn't even IN America in early 1990s. And never heard of Michael Jackson then. Second, Sir Attenborough is probably 10 times more recognizable in UK/Europe than in USA.

Comment: @DVK: you’d be down-voted out of existence over there with all this MJ hating. Separately, I think you’ve got your Attenboroughs mixed up. *Sir* Attenborough would be [David Attenborough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Attenborough), most famous for nature programmes, born on 8th May. It’s his elder brother [Richard Attenborough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Attenborough), most famous for *Jurassic Park* (possibly), who has the August 29th birthday, and he’s not Sir, merely The Right Honourable the Lord.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I think anyone arguing that Dickie Attenborough is more famous than Michael Jackson may be on a hiding to nothing...

Comment: @DKV: Michael Jackson is, by far, one of the most famous characters of 20th Century, with people like Michael Jordan, Walt Disney, Albert Einstein,.. Mr Attenborough is not, period.

Comment: I don't know who Sir Attenborough, Stephen Wolfram, or James Brady (unless you mean the former US Press Secretary under President Reagan?) are, but I sure as heck know who Michael Jackson is, and if the name "Michael Jackson" is spoken in any context, I automatically think of Michael Jackson the entertainer. Even non-fans recognize Michael Jackson's place in entertainment history; "The King of Pop" moniker is not inaccurate per se. C'mon, @DVK, [*SHAMON*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Shamon)! Tell us once again ... Who's *bad*? :D Yes, I'm silly as usual.

Comment: @Slytherincess - I agree totally; pick one :-) http://www.famousbirthdays.com/august29.html

Comment: @Richard - If I didn't pick Michael Jackson, I would, of course, have to go with Courtney Stodden (I can't even bear to explain her, ugh. Also, I don't know if she's August 29th. I just picked an August celeb.). :)

Comment: Terminator came out in late 1984. MJ's Thriller came out in 1983 and at that time he was the biggest celebrity on the planet. Everyone, or at least the target audience of teens and young adults, knew he was in his early 20's when the movie came out giving the audience a quick reference as to how far in the future the movie takes place.

Comment: I wasn't in the US in the 1990s either (and am not now either), and I, along with just about everyone else here, have absolutely known who Michael Jackson since before then, even as a kid. I now know who Sir David Attenborough is, but I didn't back then, and I've still never heard of any of the others you mention. If you hadn't heard of Michael Jackson by the 1990s, you were an anomaly. I had a pen pal from a small town in India in the early 1990s, and even she had heard of Michael Jackson (she loved his music).

Answer (score 22):

There's no definitive proof why Michael Jackson was chosen over any other celebrity but I think we can make some reasonable assumptions;

### Out-of-Universe

1. The date for Judgement Day was already mentioned in the [earlier film](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/1997/8/29). This restricts the writers to using things that are going to happen on that day.
2. Having identified the date, the writers then used Who's Who (or a magazine search at their local library) to identify celebrities with that [birth-date](https://www.famousbirthdays.com/august29.html)
3. They then selected the person on that list that was **most likely to be known by the audience and by Sarah Connor**. Michael Jackson is the most famous person with that birthday (and likely to be known by pretty much everyone watching) whereas someone like Stephen Wolfram would only be known by a tiny percentage of their target audience.

### In-Universe

On the day in question Sarah is likely to be glued to the telly waiting to see if Judgement Day is happening. Michael Jackson's 40th birthday is a big enough story that it would have made the news which is why she then references it in her diary.

Comment: And, of course, even fewer people knew who Stephen Wolfram was in 1990 (when the movie was written), or even 1997 (when Sarah Connor is meant to be speaking). Wolfram Alpha wasn’t released until 2009.

Comment: I had to Google Stephen Wolfram just now, and I STILL have no idea who he is.

Comment: For the record, they got Michael Jackson's birthday wrong. He was 39 that year, not 40

Comment: @dvk - Why the "un-accept"?

Comment: @Richard - because I still maintain that there's a marked disconnect between Judgement Day and a pop singer birthday.

Comment: @DVK - If you'd been writing a script in 1990, could you name anything else that would be as likely to be in the news on that day seven years later?

Comment: @Richard - the text didn't mention something being on the news.

Comment: I completely agree with Richard here. If Cameron had picked someone less famous, then you'd have the entire audience scratching their heads trying to figure out why that particular person was mentioned. The in-universe explanation of what's on the news that day is a logically sound one.

Comment: @PM2Ring - You are, of course, correct.